# Is there a way I can pass the "httpOnly" param to PHP's setcookie function without passing all the "extra" arguments?

Tags: php

From the [PHP's setcookie documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) the function signature is

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

If I only want to set the `$name`, `$value` and `$httponly` params, and allow the defaults to take effect for the other params. will I still have to lookup the default values for all the other optional params and set them in order to "reach" the `$httponly` param? e.g:

```
<?php
setcookie('double_track', '1234567890', 0, '', '', false, true);
                                        ^   ^   ^    ^
                                       (do I have to look  
                                        up and specify these  
                                        values?)
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native PHP methods are specified like that and you can do nothing about it.

However, you can specify your own wrapper method around the native one:

```
function setMyCookie($name, $value, $httpOnly)
{
    setcookie($name, $value, 0, '', '', false, $httpOnly);
//                           ^   ^   ^    ^
//                          (specify default values)
}
```

Now, you may just use `setMyCookie` as this:

`setMyCookie('double_track', '1234567890', true);`

Comment: ah makes sense. It might have been better if the `setcookie` function was implemented as accepting an object or associative array with named params instead? eg you set up an object `$params = [ "name" => "track_1", "value" => "2jkj34", "httponly" => true ];` and then you call with `setcookie($params);`  and internally the `setcookie`  function could loop through the array/object and use a `case` to compare and set params? ...

Comment: lol you could say that about lots of php functions. js was geat because that's how most initializers worked, but now that es6 allows default parameters that probably won't be the case anymore